# Morphia mongoDB wildcard query

Tags: regex, mongodb, wildcard, morphia, mongodb-java

Straight forward question, does anybody know how to make a wildcard query using morphia linked to a mongoDB database?

This is what the mongo statement would look like:

Mongo: `db.users.find({name:/Joe/})`
SQL:   `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "%Joe%"`

My morphia statement looks like:

Morphia: `ds.find(File.class, "filename","/test/").order("filename").asList();`

I have filenames in my database such as test1, test etc

If someone could please tell me if it's even possible with morphia it would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you refer to as a "wildcard" is in fact a "[Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)".

The Java class which represents regular expressions is the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You can pass these to the filter method of Morphia's Query object.

```
// create a regular expression which matches any string which includes "test"
Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("test");
// use this regular expression to create a query
Query q = ds.createQuery(File.class).filter("filename", regexp).sort("filename");
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work

```
DS.find(Model.class).field("filename").startsWithIgnoreCase("name").asList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Can also do:

```
ds.createQuery(File.class)
    .criteria("filename").contains("test")
    .asList();
```